# "in patients" vs "among patients"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering what the correct form is, or if both of these forms are correct:

> The IBM is the most common disease of skeletal muscle **in patients**
>   over 50 years old.
>
> The IBM is the most common disease of skeletal muscle **among
>   patients** over 50 years old.

Comment: What do Google searches for "diseases in patients" and  "disease/s among/st patients" suggest?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, as far as I saw in google scholar search, both of these forms were used.

Comment: You need to show your results in a well-presented question on ELU. Isn't "disease in patients" the clearly most frequently used form? I'd say the variants are highly synonymous, and I can't even detect different connotations here. Neither is incorrect. But 'in' is used far more commonly.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are possible. thesarus.com states **in** as a word that can replace **among** in the meaning of *being in the middle of two points.* In the example above, patients aged 50 can be described as being between two points.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/among

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is that *among patients* is better sounding, but an Ngrams search gives the following:
[image: Ngrams search]

I would say that I am significantly outnumbered in the general population in this area. If as others say the two are [interchangeable](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/among) here (since *in* is filed as synonymous with *among*), I suggest going with the majority and with '**in patients**'.

Comment: thanks! tried to upvote your answer, but my vote was only recorded as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Jack Thank you! Have 10 free rep. If you think this answer is conclusive then you can accept it add the author of the question by clicking on the tick next to the voting arrows

Answer (score 0):

I shall say AMONG and not in.
"Distribute the sweets between 2 boys" is correct.
Or "Distribute the sweets among 3 [or more] boys can be used.
We have only 2 alternatives here.
IN is not any in consideration zone, I feel.
Hope you are satisfied ?